# Cocos2D Android How to have a scene object?

Tags: android, cocos2d-android

I can get the scene from a layer, but I don't know how to have a Scene that manages layers. I can do this on iPhone, but on Android my code doesn't even get called.

This is in my start Activity:

```
CCDirector.sharedDirector().runWithScene(EditorScene.node());
```

This is my scene class:

```
public class EditorScene extends CCScene
{


public EditorScene()
{

    CanvasBackgroundLayer canvasBackgroundLayer = (CanvasBackgroundLayer) CanvasBackgroundLayer.node();
    CanvasEditorLayer canvasEditorLayer = (CanvasEditorLayer) CanvasEditorLayer.node();

    addChild(canvasBackgroundLayer,0);
    this.addChild(canvasEditorLayer);

}
}
```

My constructor here is never called.  Any ideas on what to do?

Comment: I removed the [iphone] and [cocos2d-iphone] tags because your questions aren't related to the iphone version of Cocos2D.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any subclasses of CCScene have to reimplement the static method node(). Have a look at the bottom of CCScene.h.